# Display two array object data alternatively in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have one object as `arrayobj1=[{"name":"hello1","age":"12"},{"name":"hello2","age":"115"}] and arrayobj2=[{"name":"hello3","age":"12"},{"name":"hello4","age":"12"}]`

I want to display in html in table  alternatively as

```
Hello1
Hello3
Hello2
Hello4
```

My code format to follow

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of arrayobj1">
<td>obj.name</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let obj of arrayobj2">
<td>obj.name</td>
</tr>
```

But this only print the first how do I print both the loops alternatively.

Comment: Why don’t you merge those 2 arrays into 3rd array sequentially and print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays are always equal size, just use the index from either array. Since you want a separate row for each, you can use an `ng-container` to apply the same `ngFor` directive to both rows.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let _ of arrayobj1; index as i">
  <tr><td>{{ arrayobj1[i].name }}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>{{ arrayobj2[i].name }}</td></tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What if those arrays have different length?

Comment: @Rana_S Depends on what you want to happen. For example, if you only want to print the indices that exist in both arrays, you could provide the array with minimum length to the `ngFor` directive. You could make a method to compare lengths and return the smaller array. @Mayur would need to provide more details for what they want to happen when the arrays are not equal length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the `ngFor` and add a `ngIf` to hide the row you want !

For example:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of arrayobj1; let i =  index">
<td *ngIf="i % 2">obj.name</td>
</tr>
```